# What's the best way to effectively report bugs?

Tags: freeze, kde, bug-reporting, plasma

I've been trying to report a bug about Activities in Kubuntu causing me no end of grief with multiple issues ranging from annoying to total freeze/crash requiring hardware reset. I'm trying to follow official instructions to make sure I file my problems correctly starting at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kubuntu/Bugs/ReportingBugs

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

The above is circular reference with no obvious alternative path for Kubuntu users.

Alternatively using Ubuntu instead of Kubuntu links from ReportingBugs clicking
for 3. Make sure the bug hasn't already been reported (11.04 Natty) 
at the following link in the Kubuntu section there are only 6 listed bugs:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ReleaseNotes

none of which apply to me and no further guidance other than a link to the 
following at the bottom of the page which takes me back to our old friend:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

now trying instructions at 
4. Filing a general bug against no particular package to run `ubuntu-bug`

Using that tool tells me to uninstall nvidia drivers that I needed to fix previous crash problem with resizing Konsole causing a freeze. After refusing to uninstall my drivers it then it suggests I try going here to http://askubuntu.com

Other than asking this question I see no other solution, so I guess my question is:

What the heck am I supposed to do a proper bug report or get a solution to my never ending issues with Kubuntu and KDE 4's Plasma and especially Activities?

Answer (score 5):

The Package you would want to run the Ubuntu-Bug script against is `plasma-desktop` so th full command would be

```
ubuntu-bug plasma-desktop
```

you can run this command from a terminal or by pressing alt+f2 and pasting the command in the text box.

If you find a bug matching yours you can add yourself bay marking that this bug affects you too or starting a new bug if none match your circumstances and give information that it is the Activities plasmoid that is causing the crash/freeze. Obviously you will need to set up an account in launchpad first before reporting the bug.