# What is the right way for reporting bugs?

Tags: bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)
>   [What's the best way to effectively report bugs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59154/whats-the-best-way-to-effectively-report-bugs)

I want to report a bug in the Unity Launcher (as soon as you drop an application -namely evolution- there, it reserves the space but doesn't show the icon until you log out and log back in).
Following the advice in Ubuntu's web page, I tried running "ubuntu-bug unity" but it displays a message saying the development ended and so on... It says I can continue if I was referred by technical support.
I think reporting bugs should be extremely easy for users that want to collaborate, but it seems the other way around. 
Finally, my question: what is the "proper" way for reporting bugs?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question fully. Do you want me to report a bug for you with the info you gave?

Comment: No. hat is an example of what detail is needed.